# Is it possible to redefine the screen viewport or have a "not-so-to-the-right" fixed aligned element?

Tags: html, css

I'm toying around with a `position:fixed` layout. However, it look too wide, so I though I would simply put my page inside a container with a `max-width` property, but it doesn't work, fixed elements take the viewport top/bottom/left/right position of the viewport and not of the parent, although they are positionned where I want them if a position is not defined.

I'd like to have **2 fixed elements** at the top of my page, contained inside a max-width.
first element aligned to the left (no `left:0px` required)
second element aligned to the right (`right:0px` required (or something else?)

Could I redefine the viewport?
Do you see any alternative?

[Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/qDSvV/1/) code :

*Note : stuff2 yellow background needs to be aligned with the `.page` background.*

html

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header1">
        stuff1
    </div>
    <div class="header2">
        stuff2
    </div>
    other stuff1<br />
    other stuff2<br />
    other stuff3<br />
    other stuff4<br />
    other stuff5<br />
</div>
```

css

```
html,body {padding:0px;margin:0px;height:100%}

.page {
    max-width:700px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background:#ffddff;
    min-height:100%;
}

.header1 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    background:#eeffff;
    max-width:700px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

.header2 {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    background:#ffffee;
    max-width:700px;
    width:30%;
    height:50px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: are you thinking more along the lines of this? http://jsfiddle.net/LNDeq/  It looks like you might need position:absolute rather than fixed.

Comment: @Joseph : Then I loose the header if I scroll down, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closer but might not be quite right.  I'll work on it more later if this doesn't work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/A5NX9/

Comment: I like how you did this. both header take 100% width, overlapping. Their content is what redefine them. [Why should we keep both floating element?](http://jsfiddle.net/A5NX9/1/) :)

Comment: @Kraz I'm afraid to look at my code. XD I was a bit rushed at that time yesterday so it was a little messy, but yes, your code looks much better and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is use floats so they align to each other and then push the rest of the content down. I set it up here based on your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/uWxTw/2/

Comment: Nop, I really want my header to be `position:fixed`. I don't want it to dissapear if the content gets long. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/uWxTw/3/)

Comment: Without using some javascript like a person outlines in this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155894/position-a-fixed-element-relative-to-a-containing-element) the only other way I can see this working is what I set up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uWxTw/6/) where I put the right fixed div inside its own right floated div and then set widths to both divs. It actually seems to be working quite well but not sure how accurate it is.

Comment: Your solution with the float is nice, although it requires to have a fixed width to the 2nd header. Thanks :)